# How to remove Analysis button from Webform results tab

Tags: webforms

I am trying to located the template file or function that outputs the following buttonson the webform results tab

Secondary tabs

```
Submissions(active tab)
Analysis
Table
Download
Clear
```

Can anyone advise how I can tweak/remove/hide some of these

Answer (score 3):

The best way to hide menu item from the secondary tabs should be to alter the access callback of the menu item.

```
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$item) {
  // This hides the analysis item. Others should work simillary.
  $item['node/%webform_menu/webform-results/analysis']['access callback'] = 'yourmodule_webform_result_access';
}

function yourmodule_webform_result_access($node, $account = NULL) {
  // You can put here any custom logic of your needs.
  return FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: What if i want to restrict access to analysis to all except administrator ?